# get message from gRPC java server side interceptor

Tags: grpc, interceptor, grpc-java

I am writing a gRPC server side interceptor in java. I simplely want to access the request message and read one field from the message. But after 1 day of googling and talking with others, I couldn't find how to do it.

**Any idea how to do it?**

```
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;

public class EventInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {


    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
            Metadata metadata,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {

        // TODO: Get the request message here
        return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request message arrives later. You need to return your own listener to observe the message.

```java
import io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener;

public class EventInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
            Metadata metadata,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        ServerCall.Listener listener = serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
        return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(listener) {
            @Override public void onMessage(ReqT req) {
                // You now have access to the request(s)
                doWork(req);
                super.onMessage(req);
            }
        };
    }
}
```